# Laravel return empty relationship on model when condidtion is true

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, relationship

I have a model where I want to return a empty value when a condition happens, but when I try to get the model:

```
Model::with('shop')->find(id);
```

I get this error:

> "Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null"

This is the code I'm trying:

```
public function shop(){
    if(true) {
        return null;
    }
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Shop');
}
```

How is the proper way to return nothing when a condition is true on Laravel relationships?

Comment: how do you call the relation?

Comment: @ab_ab edited the question.

Comment: can we see the detailed error?

Comment: @ab_ab there's the trace error

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you could use this trick - set an impossible query condition when a condition met:

```
public function shop(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Shop')->where(function($query) {

        if ($condition) {

            // I think this should do the trick
            $query->whereNull('id');
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: It doesn't throw the error but it's returning an empty array, when I want to have a null value there.

Comment: Hmm on my code I tried and it return me null actually. Perhaps it's a 5.1 thing. Let me check

Comment: Did a fresh install and it works, for belongsTo relationships, if they are hasMany returns an empty array. Your code is correct.

Comment: Yea by right it should be null on 1 record, or empty array/collection if have many. It's still respect to the standard query :)

Answer (score 7):

Correct way to return a `BelongsTo` instance.

```
public function shop(): BelongsTo
{
    if(true) {
        return new BelongsTo($this->newQuery(), $this, '', '', '');
    }
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Shop');
}
```

Comment: I prefer this because it returns a BelongsTo

Comment: When i used this, the collection resource gived an error like Error: Call to a member function first() on null in file C:\xampp\htdocs\www\big_crm\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Resources\CollectsResources.php on line 29

Answer (score 5):

Wrap your query in the [rescue](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-rescue) helper:

```
// continue processing if an exception happens.
// return some default value if the query does not succeed, null for example.
return rescue(function () {
    // some custom logic here
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Shop');
}, null);
```

**updated**

For 5.1 try returning a new model instance:

```
public function shop(){
    if(true) {
        return new static;
    }
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Shop');
}
```

**update 2**

Try returning the model's [query builder](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1785):

```
public function shop(){
    if(true) {
        return $this->newQuery(); // or newQueryWithoutScopes()
    }
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Shop');
}
```

Comment: It will work for Laravel 5.6, but I'm using Laravel 5.1 :)

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't notice the 5.1 tag.

Comment: Upvoted becasue it's the proper way to do it on Laravel +5.5.