# Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null because of a conditional relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I have to deal with a Laravel 7 application that has a sub-optimal database design, leading to the error mentioned in the title.

The database looks like this:

```
mains
- id
- sub_type

subs_a
- id
- main_id

subs_b
- id
- main_id
```

Then I have a class `Main` with method `sub`:

```
public function sub()
{
    switch($this->sub_type) {
        case 'a':
            return $this->hasOne('SubTypeA');
            break;
        case 'b':
            return $this->hasOne('SubTypeB');
            break;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

This code works in 99% of all cases, but Laravel sometimes loads an empty instance of `Main` and then tries to load the relations. That doesn't work, because the default of method `sub` is `null`.

Restructuring the database is on the to-do list, but that isn't of any help right now.

What option do I have to stop Laravel from trying to load the `sub` relation on an empty object?

Comment: this isn't how relationships work .. you don't do things like this ... unless you are directly calling a relationship method on a specific model instance there will never be attributes as it will use a new model instance to get the relationship object to perform the query needed  .... this looks like you are trying to do a polymorphic relationship (which eloquent supports)

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I'm aware of the sub-optimal database design and the code that follows that design. But it's a live application; I cannot just restructure everything in a few hours.

Comment: you also are not showing how you are doing the query or accessing the relationship currently

Comment: I'm not accessing anything manually. There's a `Notification` that has a `Main` object, and that `Notification` implements `ShouldQueue`. When the object is (re)loaded, I get this error. But not always.

Comment: the impact would be that if your default is to return one of those relationships then it will look in that table, which may not be correct ... that is the impact so it might return a result that is not the actual existing relationship since `main_id` could exist in both tables

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. So that eliminates that option. Is there any way to prevent Laravel from calling `sub` on an empty `Main` object?

Comment: Can you provide on where this method is used?

Comment: The method `sub` isn't used manually. Laravel calls it to eagerly load the relation.

Comment: create two relations `subTypeA()` and `subTypeB`. Retrieve the `Main` object and check your condition and apply `load('subTypeA')` or ``load('subTypeB')` based on conditions in your controller. Like,`if($main->sub_type == 'a') { $main->load('subTypeA');}`

Comment: @Sherlock I have updated my answer, I would like to know, what is your thoughts on that.

Comment: @Sherlock I would like to know if you have solved it, if yes it will be great, if you will post the solution if no, would like to know the status.

Comment: None of the suggestions worked for me, I'm just refactoring this entire bit of the application.

Answer (score 4):

i know it's some kind of expected, but have tried to return an empty relation?

```
public function sub()
{
    switch($this->sub_type) {
        case 'a':
            return $this->hasOne('SubTypeA');
            break;
        case 'b':
            return $this->hasOne('SubTypeB');
            break;
        default:
            return $this->newQuery();  // or newQueryWithoutScopes()
    }
}
```

thank to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49812170/10573560). it should prevent the error of addEagerConstraints() on null.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this didn't work for me unfortunately. newQuery is not a Relationship object, so I still get an error on `addEagerConstraints`.

Answer (score 0):

Few things I would like to point out about it is, your relationship should not be conditional, after making the default relationship what you want to make you can define [scope](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#query-scopes) instead and manage stuffs or use [withDefault](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#default-models) return something in failure case.

About the error calling a member function on null:- below is another example

```
<?php
class MyClass{
    function bar(){
        echo "something";
    }
}

class MyAnotherClass{
    function foo(){
        if (1>2) {
            $obj = new MyClass();
            $obj->x = $x;
            $obj->y = $y;
            $obj->save();
            return $obj;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

$myAnotherObj = new MyAnotherClass();
$myClass = $myAnotherObj->foo();
$myClass->bar()
?>
```

Instead of doing it, I would prefer throwing an exception and handling it, so that I will get specific reason for failure, in Laravel [rescue](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-rescue) helper function you can choose to use.

```
<?php
class MyClass{
    function bar(){
        echo "something";
    }
}

class MyAnotherClass{
    function foo(){
        if (1>2) {
            $obj = new MyClass();
            $obj->x = $x;
            $obj->y = $y;
            $obj->save();
            return $obj;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("could not create my class object", 100); // Better to create custom exception class here
        }
    }
}

$myAnotherObj = new MyAnotherClass();
try {
    $myClass = $myAnotherObj->foo();
    $myClass->bar();
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

if for me the data is not so important I will think of creating an empty object

```
<?php
    class MyClass{
        function bar(){
            echo "something";
        }
    }
    
    class MyAnotherClass{
        function foo(){
            $obj = new MyClass();
            if (1>2) {
                $obj->x = $x;
                $obj->y = $y;
                $obj->save();  
            } 
            return $obj;
        }
    }
    
    $myAnotherObj = new MyAnotherClass();
    $myClass = $myAnotherObj->foo();
    $myClass->bar()
  ?>
```

but if you are making an operation with that object properties, then the properties will be null instead of object, so based on the how discipline you will be when using it, you can take decision.

**How I would have like to handled your situation?**

*Exception class*

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;

class SubTypeNotFound extends Exception {
    public function report()
    {
        \Log::debug('Could not find this subtype');
    }
}
```

?>

*Model class*

```
<?php
class Mains extends Model
{
    public function subA()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(SubTypeA::class);
    }    

    public function subB()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(SubTypeB::class);
    }

    public function scopeSub($query, $type)
    {
        return $query
          ->when($type === 'a',function($q){
              return $q->with('subA');
         })
         ->when($type === 'b',function($q){
              return $q->with('subB');
         }),function($q){
             throw SubTypeNotFound();
         });
    }
}
?>
```

*while retrieving it*

```
try {
    $sub = Mains::sub('a')->get();
} catch(SubTypeNotFound $e) {
    return $e->getMessage();
}
```

If you have `$this->sub_type` you can avoid using the `type` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the effort! I decided to fix it by refactoring the entire class and its relations.

Comment: @Sherlock I would like to see, how you did it, if there is no issue, please post your solution too.

Comment: @Sherlock also I would like to know, what is the demerits of using scope?

Answer (score -2):

You can simply put if condition before switch case.

```
public function sub()
{
    if($this->sub_type){
        switch($this->sub_type) {
            case 'a':
                return $this->hasOne('SubTypeA');
                break;
            case 'b':
                return $this->hasOne('SubTypeB');
                break;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }else{
        return null
    }       
}
```